# How to transform this raw table with SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, etl

I need funnel analysis. How can I transform raw data with SQL?

My approach was

1. case when (get time diff over partitioned uid orderly time) > 1min(
   this is a threshold). then 1. else 0 end alias **start**.
2. and groupby **start** get cumsum.
3. and groupby cumsum concat event

I think this process would take a long time and how to get begin_date and end_date.
I do not know how to query the sql statement exactly.

[image]

Comment: Don't use images of data (would you like an image of a solution query?). Please provide your sample data as a text table in your question, Then we might be able to answer. Providing the query you have tried to use also tells us useful things e.g. the table name

Comment: found a [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839900/sql-to-get-transformed-data-from-this-raw-data-for-funnel-analysis) quite by accident with the data in text... you could have used that instead of the image.

Comment: This could be a good and useful question if you had taken the time to follow the instruction provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8b5ba/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "datetime" time, "name" varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "datetime", "name")
VALUES
    (1, '11:10:01', 'A'),
    (1, '11:10:02', 'A'),
    (1, '11:10:05', 'B'),
    (1, '11:12:02', 'A'),
    (1, '11:12:10', 'A'),
    (2, '11:13:02', 'B'),
    (2, '11:13:06', 'A'),
    (1, '11:14:01', 'A'),
    (1, '11:14:02', 'B'),
    (1, '11:14:05', 'A')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select
     id, datetime, name
  , row_number() over(partition by id, date_trunc('minute',datetime) order by datetime) rn
  , lead(name) over(partition by id, date_trunc('minute',datetime) order by datetime) lead_name
  from table1
  )
, cte2 as (
    select
    id, date_trunc('minute',datetime) t, concat(name,lead_name) pair
    from cte
    where lead_name IS NOT NULL
   )
select
       id
     , t
     , count(case when pair = 'AA' then 1 end) as AA
     , count(case when pair = 'AB' then 1 end) as AB
     , count(case when pair = 'BA' then 1 end) as BA
     , count(case when pair = 'BB' then 1 end) as BB
from cte2
group by
       id
     , t
order by
       id
     , t
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8b5ba/2/0)**:

```
| id |                                                t | aa | ab | ba | bb |
|----|--------------------------------------------------|----|----|----|----|
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 10 mins 0.00 secs |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 12 mins 0.00 secs |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 14 mins 0.00 secs |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|  2 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 13 mins 0.00 secs |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |
```

---

**Query v2**:

```
with cte as (
  select
     id, datetime, name
  , row_number() over(partition by id order by datetime) rn
  , lead(name) over(partition by id order by datetime) lead_name
  from table1
  )
, cte2 as (
    select
    id, date_trunc('minute',datetime) t, concat(name,lead_name) pair
    from cte
    where lead_name IS NOT NULL
   )
select
       id
     , t
     , count(case when pair = 'AA' then 1 end) as AA
     , count(case when pair = 'AB' then 1 end) as AB
     , count(case when pair = 'BA' then 1 end) as BA
     , count(case when pair = 'BB' then 1 end) as BB
from cte2
group by
       id
     , t
order by
       id
     , t
;
```

**[Results v2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8b5ba/2/0)**:

```
| id |                                                t | aa | ab | ba | bb |
|----|--------------------------------------------------|----|----|----|----|
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 10 mins 0.00 secs |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 12 mins 0.00 secs |  2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|  1 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 14 mins 0.00 secs |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|  2 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 11 hours 13 mins 0.00 secs |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. If you look at [this query variant](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8b5ba/2) if you **remove**  `, date_trunc('minute',datetime)` from the row_number() and lead() partitions it may be a more accurate solution.